# Strawberry Blond

Tags: beer, fruit

This is my second attempt at home brewing, my first came out very well.  I added a couple of pounds of strawberries to my primary.  After one month a racked to my secondary.  I was not expecting to see such nasty looking strawberries.  Most of it was clearly eaten bu the Yeast but the ones that remained were grey in color.  To be safe I was extra conservative when racking and left a good inch and change at the bottom in order to take as little of the solids as possible.  The beer in the secondary looks fine, a little cloudy but I expect that to settle.  Has anyone ever done this before and had a similar experience?  I want to make sure it is safe to drink etc.

Thanks.

Comment: See this question with respect to whether or not it's safe to drink: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/6230/is-it-ever-unsafe-to-drink-an-aged-beer

Answer (score 3):

Beer does tend to bleach out the strawberries, its perfectly normal.
I make strawberry blond the same way every summer.  The berries come out pretty scary sometimes.

Comment: one of life's wonders I've yet to experience! scary strawberries!

Answer (score 0):

Let us know how this turns out.  In Radical Brewing, Mosher says that strawberries rarely live up to their promise of beautiful fresh aromatics and perfect balance of sweet/tart when added to beer.  Pick up a beer thief though, or sanitize a turkey baster.  The only way to ever know if fermentation is completed (or if your beer is ruined, aside from a bacterial pellicle) is to check gravity (and taste afterwards!)